# Aurospike maximum keys count limit?

Tags: aerospike

How many keys can store in an Aerospike instance?

Answer (score 2):

The Aerospike community version has the same limit as the Redis, 4,294,967,296 records can store in a single node and single namespace of Aerospike.

Full list of limits are [here](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/limitations.html)

Comment: As mentioned on the link you posted, the Enterprise Edition has a much higher limit (half a trillion per node per namespace).